# Replicate Dynamics CRM 2013 security

Tags: 2013, integration, dynamics-crm

What do you think is the best approach to replicate Dynamics CRM 2013 (on-premises) security into SharePoint 2013 (on-premises)? I know there are couple tools/plugins out there for the purpose but still I want to know what's the best approach (concerning scalability).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to research this software:

[CB Dynamics CRM – SharePoint Permissions Replicator](https://www.connecting-software.com/dynamics-crm-sharepoint-permissions-replicator/)